# NextJS returning environment variables as undefined in pages

Tags: next.js

I am trying to get my environment variables in one of my pages, but it is always returning undefined. I have no issues with accessing the variables in  `api` folder but in `pages/page.tsx` it doesn't return the variables.

I access my variables using

`const SECRET = process.env.SECRET` from my `.env` file.

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the preferred way to implement what you're trying to do is to use env variables on the server side within getServerSideProps()/getStaticProps() methods. This should work as expected without any tricks.

But if you want to access env variables on the client you have to prefix your variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_

Please refer to official [docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser):

> By default all environment variables loaded through .env.local are only available in the Node.js environment, meaning they won't be exposed to the browser.
>
> In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the variable with NEXT_PUBLIC_. For example:
>
> `NEXT_PUBLIC_ANALYTICS_ID=abcdefghijk`

Comment: This will be exposed to users. if I want to load it in my pages I need to put them in env.local?

Comment: @ashes999 Using .env file should work as well. I've also updated answer with more information